# How to display figure in the same windows using tkinter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm working on "Image retrieval", which take query image from user and displaying 10 images ( top ) which similar to query. I'm made the UI using tkinter, the images displaying as a plot in new figure, but I want to display display them in the first windows under "upload image" button.

[image: Output images]

Also, if there is another way is better than it, (instead of ploting it) please inform me.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

windows = tk.Tk()
windows.geometry("380x250")  # Size of the window

windows.title('Content-based Medical Image Retrieval')
font_style = ('Comic Sans MS', 16, 'bold')
l1 = tk.Label(windows, text='Upload Image & Display Results',
              width=30, font=font_style)
#l1.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4)
l1.pack( expand=1)
font_style = ('Calibri', 10, 'bold')
upload_button = tk.Button(windows, text='Upload Image',
               width=20,height = 2,font=font_style, command=lambda: upload_file())
#upload_button.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=4)
upload_button.pack( expand=1)

def upload_file():
    f_types = [('Jpg Files', '*.jpg'),
               ('PNG Files', '*.png')]   # type of files to select
    filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True, filetypes=f_types)
    class_name = str(list(filename))[-16:-13].replace("/","")
    print(class_name)
    list_all_images_in_class = os.listdir(dataset_path+'/'+class_name)

    image_path = str(list(filename))[2:-2]
    print(image_path)
    average_precision=0
    list_all_images_in_class=os.listdir(dataset_path+'/'+class_name)
    query_image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    query_image = cv2.cvtColor(query_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
    gabor_output=Gabor_Filter(query_image)
    schmid_output=Schmid_Filter(query_image)
    query_vectors=Image_Partition(gabor_output+schmid_output)
    query_vectors = np.array(query_vectors)
    query_classify=kmeans.predict(query_vectors)
    query_histogram,_=np.histogram(query_classify,bins=range(n_dic+1),density=True)

    list_amount_similarity = []
    for x in range(num_of_img):    
        similarity_result=hist_match(list_histogram_of_each_image_in_dataset[x],query_histogram)
        list_amount_similarity.append((similarity_result,str(list_images_path[x])))

    total_image_retrieved=10
    top_image_retrieved = sorted(list_amount_similarity,reverse=True)[:total_image_retrieved]

    path_retrieved_image=[]
    retrieved_image_class=[]
    similarity_result=[]
    count =0

    for similarity_amount, image_path in top_image_retrieved:
        similarity_result.append(similarity_amount) 
        path_retrieved_image.append(image_path)
        class_path=os.path.dirname(image_path)
        retrieved_image_class.append(os.path.basename(class_path)) 

    plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
    plt.subplot(441);plt.imshow(query_image)
    plt.title('Query');plt.axis('off')


    retrieved_image =[]
    relevant_images=0 

    #calculate the pecision for each query 
    #and then add the pecision to the average_precision
    if int(class_name)==1: 
        for i in range(total_image_retrieved):
            retrieved_image.append(imageio.imread(path_retrieved_image[i]))
            plt.subplot(4,4,i+2); plt.imshow(retrieved_image[i])
            
            plt.title('%d, %.4f,%d' % (i,similarity_result[i],int(retrieved_image_class[i])));plt.axis('off')  
            if int(retrieved_image_class[i])==1:
                relevant_images +=1
        precision=relevant_images/total_image_retrieved
        average_precision+=precision      

    elif int(class_name) ==2:
        for i in range(total_image_retrieved):
            retrieved_image.append(imageio.imread(path_retrieved_image[i]))
            plt.subplot(4,4,i+2); plt.imshow(retrieved_image[i])
            plt.title('%d, %.4f,%d' % (i,similarity_result[i],int(retrieved_image_class[i])));plt.axis('off')  
            #sim.setText(f"similarity: {int(retrived_imgs[i][0] * 100)}%")
            if int(retrieved_image_class[i])==2:
                relevant_images +=1
        precision=relevant_images/total_image_retrieved
        average_precision+=precision 
        
windows.mainloop()
```